# Asking about solutions for the "outdated answers" problem in the survey

Tags: discussion, survey, outdated-information, short-survey

I just clicked on the *"Take our short survey"* link at the top of SO and started to fill out the survey.

Near the end of the survey, it asked me about *possible solutions* regarding the "outdated answers" problem: Whether I'd like to have the sort order changed, whether I'd like a "this is outdated" banner, etc.

**This is a great question.** I have never thought about the "outdated answers" problem, but you are right: It's a valid problem that should be addressed.

The thing is: I'm an experienced software engineer, and it would take me *at least* 30 minutes to think about the different solutions, compare the pros and cons, and then choose to most appropriate one. I'm really not sure if a challenging design problem is an appropriate question for a "short survey".

I ended up not answering because I currently don't have the time to give this interesting problem the appropriate amount of care and thought. A banner like this might have been more helpful:

> We want to solve the "outdated answers" problem. [Read our design proposals](https://example.com) and then [provide feedback in our survey regarding this topic](https://example.com).

Or did I misunderstand the question and you just want to collect quick "gut-feeling" answers?

Comment: @Tomerikoo: No, it doesn't. It's a different question altogether. :-) I was *not* asking about more information regarding the "outdated answers" problem, I was giving feedback to "asking about it in the survey".

Comment: You might want to post your concern there as it is the discussion about this subject...

Comment: @Tomerikoo: No, because the other question *explicitly* says "Starting March 31 and running through April 15, we added a few questions to the monthly survey to further validate some of the Meta suggestions with a larger audience. **(Please note: we are not soliciting feedback on these questions.)**". So my point is explicitly declared as off-topic in the other question.

Comment: Given it is the "short-survey" I don't expect to have to spend 30 minutes of your time is warranted. So a "gut-feeling" will do. I see it more as  a discovery of which options to further investigate.  Do sign-up in your profile for invites on UX research. I've participated in a few and that is the right venue to go deep into details indeed for 30 minutes or more.

Comment: What is the question here? (I think you made a great observation and I too thought that the answers to question 1 are pretty useless because you basically ask people things that are difficult to know and you may sample more noise than signal. But still I wonder what kind of input you expect here?) Do you want to know what level of participation in the survey the company expects from participants?

Comment: @Trilarion: Well, possible answers include "Oh, yes, you're right, thanks, we'll do that differently next time. Chees, *someone with a diamond*" or "We thought about that beforehand and decided to do it anyways because *some smart reasoning that I didn't think of*" or "I like that banner proposal and have a few improvement suggestions: ..." or what rene wrote in the comments. In any case, my main purpose was to give feedback and give others the opportunity to agree or point out mistakes, which [is OK according to the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Yes, I only wanted to know what feedback you exactly want to obtain. Rather a confirmation of your observation or a rationale of why this part of the survey was conducted in that way and what the survey conductors hoped to achieve or something else. I was a bit lost and thought this is too much open ended without some more guidance from you. I actually think you did not misunderstand the question.

Comment: @Trilarion: Makes sense. In that case, I'll clarify that my main purpose was *giving* feedback. *Getting* some in return is something I'll gladly take but do not expect. :-)